# Razor foreach loop inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, razor, charts, foreach

I'm creating a google chart and I have now made it look like I want it to with amounts of lines/bars and multiple axises and so on, now I want to have dynamic data inside of it.

```
function drawVisualization()
{
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

        ['Day', 'KG', 'Average', 'peak'],

        ['1', 22000, 70, 90],

        ['2', 21000, 80, 87],

        ['3', 19000, 75, 79],

        ['4', 25000, 60, 88],

        ['5', 24000, 90, 95]
 ]);
```

So as of right now this is how the data is sent to the chart, 1,2,3,4,5 for hAxis and the rest for vAxis.

However I thought I could use a foreach in here and do something like this to return data:

```
@foreach (var c in db.Query(getWorkout))
{
    ['1', @c.kg, @c.rep, @c.sett];
}
```

The foreach actually works while no code is inside it so I guess the errors are all due to `['1', @c.kg, @c.rep, @c.sett];` this.

Anyone got any ideas of what to do? Would be tremendously thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following

```
@foreach (var c in db.Query(getWorkout))
{
    <text>['1', @c.kg, @c.rep, @c.sett],</text>
}
```

Comment: awesome! I did try `<text>` but around the entire foreach which didn't work but this did, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work

first create an array in JavaScript

```
var dbData = [['Day', 'KG', 'Average', 'peak']];
```

then use razor `@foreach` to append data

```
@foreach (var c in db.Query(getWorkout))
{
  dbData.push(['1', @c.kg, @c.rep, @c.sett]);
}
```

then

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dbData);
```